# Name for the operation $v \cdot M \cdot {v^T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Just wondering if there is a name for the operation of multiplying 1xN vector by an NxN matrix and then by the transpose of the vector. My feeble memory says that such a name might exist, perhaps in the context of statistics (e.g. if the matrix is a covariance matrix). Thanks, Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is - sandwiching $M$ with $v$. It is widely accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called a [Quadratic Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form)